# Assignment to constant variable (DISCORD.JS)

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a probleme, I want to make a setprefix command like that:

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'setprefix')) {
        var usermsg = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
        if (!usermsg[0]) return message.delete().then(console.log('[', 'ERROR'.red, ']', 'un argument est nécessaire'))
        prefix = usermsg
        const setprefix = (`prefix changé en: ${usermsg}`)
        message.delete()
        message.channel.send(setprefix)
    }
```

but i have this error:

```
        prefix = usermsg
               ^

TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
```

What did I must do ?

Comment: JavaScript 101, you cant reassign to a constant variable. Change the definition to use `let`. I recommend you learn JavaScript basics before using a JavaScript library.

Comment: If prefix is gonna change, you shouldn’t make it a constant

Answer (score 1):

According to your error, there appears to be a constant named as `prefix` and you are trying to change the value of the constant. This is a really easy mistake to make especially for beginners who have just started learning something in JavaScript. I would recommend that you actually take a course on learning basic JS before attempting Discord.JS since there are a lot of mistakes which can be made if you don't know the basics. For your question, all you have to do is, in the line of code where you declare the constant `prefix`, instead of using `const prefix`, change it to `let prefix`